# What application is sending notification?

Tags: notify-osd, spotify, notify-send

I've got Spotify for Linux installed and for some reason I was getting duplicated notifications for song changes (different text as well). Now one of them is very bad, as it just shows the song title. The second one comes from `spotify-notify` (which I installed myself). I've been trying to figure out what program sends this other notification but to no avail. Is there a way to identify this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest Spotify release has inbuilt notifications. You don't need `spotify-notify` anymore.

Comment: Aha! I see, is there a way to change the format, or disable it so I only have `spotify-notify`? I'm saying because Spotify's built in notifications are horrible. It shows only the song title and sometimes the album title.

Comment: @HoshSadiq [You can disable the notifications](http://askubuntu.com/a/472329/81372), but this will also [remove the DBUS interface that spotify-notify uses](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/Linux-Desktop-notifications/m-p/879531/highlight/true#M94487). Unfortunately you will have to choose between no notifications at all, both notification systems at once, or the lacking inbuilt ones only :/. Hopefully this will be fixed with the next update.