# Removing popup notifications on Spotify Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, spotify

This is the issue (and solution) I'm talking about:

[Remove spotify pop-up notification when a song starts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472325/remove-spotify-pop-up-notification-when-a-song-starts)

However in terminal when I run the first command I receive a Permission denied error...any way I can get around this ?

Thanks !

Comment: There are no commands in that solution, you just have to modify a file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a command.

> then edit `~/.config/spotify/Users/[Spotify user name]-user/prefs` [...]

It's asking you to edit a file. So either find the file through Nautilus, or track it down in a terminal and edit it with Gedit or nano or butterflies or whatever you like to use to edit things.