# How can I find a folder that starts with a .?

Tags: command-line, permissions, google-chrome, spotify, preferences

I've just read [this answer about changing Spotify preferences](https://askubuntu.com/a/472329/186134), but I don't understand; where can I find the file `~/.config/spotify/Users/[Spotify user name]-user/prefs` to be able to edit it? Do I have to use the Terminal?

If possible, can you explain step by step how to find `~/.config/spotify/Users/[Spotify user name]/prefs`?

#### Edit

I found it using Google Chrome:

```
file:///home/tim/.config/spotify/Users/tim/prefs
```

But I cant edit it. How do I edit a file in a folder that starts with a `.`? Do I need to be root user?

Comment: CTRL+H while in `~`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like kos said:

In nautilus you can use CTRL + H to show hidden files.

Or you can use terminal:

```
nano /home/tim/.config/spotify/Users/tim/prefs
```

or if you want to use gedit to edit to file:

```
gedit /home/tim/.config/spotify/Users/tim/prefs
```