# No Spotify notifications

Tags: spotify

How do I disable Spotify notifications?
[Remove spotify pop-up notification when a song starts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472325/remove-spotify-pop-up-notification-when-a-song-starts) doesn't work, as there's nothing called "*notification*" in the `~/.config/spotify/Users/[Spotify user name]-user/prefs` file

Comment: I tried to disable in the display options but it only show to have show unavailable songs in playlist, show announcements, and show friend feed, there's nothing about show desktop notification

Answer (score 3):

As @edwinksl said in a comment you can actually do this right from the GUI.

1. Hit the down arrow in the top right corner
2. Select the settings option
3. Last option under 'Display Options' should read 'Show desktop notification....' tap/click that and they'll be disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, simply adding `ui.track_notifications_enabled=false` as the first line of the file works. It's apparently normal if the field doesn't exist

Comment: I have always disabled this inside the Spotify GUI client actually. Do you see the "Show desktop notifications when the song changes" option in "Settings"?

Answer (score 0):

Quit Spotify and add `ui.track_notifications_enabled=false` in a new line anywhere in this file:

```
~/.config/spotify/Users/[spotify-user-name]-user/prefs
```

or `~/snap/spotify/current/.config/spotify/Users/[spotify-user-name]-user/prefs`

and save.

- If nothing has changed, make sure you have quit Spotify and try editing the file again.
- If the `prefs` file doesn't exist create it and add mentioned line.

---

Also, you can change it in Spotify itself:

**Settings > Display Options** and toggle off: *Show desktop notifications when the song changes*